# File 'app/hero.ts' is not a module error in the console, where to store interfaces files in directory structure with angular2?

Tags: angular

I am doing the `angular2` tutorial at this address: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html I have put the `hero` interface in a single file under the `app` folder, in the console I have this error:

```
app/app.component.ts(2,20): error TS2306: File 'app/hero.ts' is not a module.
[0] app/hero-detail.component.ts(2,20): error TS2306: File 'app/hero.ts' is not a module.
```

If I put my interface file in a hero folder the error disappear, **this is not mentioned in the documentation, what's wrong with my import**?

My import directive (at the beguining of the component files) in both `app.components.ts` and `hero-detail.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {Hero} from './hero';
```

**Must I replace** my import directive by: `import {Hero} from './';` **or simply put the code in a hero folder**?

Answer (score 466, accepted):

Try Restarting the editor in which you are writing the code(VS code or Sublime).
Compile and Run it again. I have done the same and it worked.

This happens when you add a new class outside from your editor or keep running your angular cli 'ng serve'. Actually your editor or the 'ng serve' command may not able to find the newly created files.

Comment: Restarting works ... but anyone know What is the root cause?

Comment: I also ran into this problem with Angular 4 and VS Code.  I was following one of the videos on Code School where they separate the data into a mocks.ts file, and every time it compiled, it said it wasn't a module.  Restarting VS Code worked.  It's very strange that this happened, but I didn't get any errors when moving other pieces into separate files.

Comment: Restarting did nothing for me.  I had to rename the problem class, and the file that contained it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that restarting helps because you forgot to save a file. In my case (who is used to intellij idea but used Atom in this case) I did forget to save the newly created hero.ts file. As long as you don't save it ng serve cannot build it :)

Comment: It's sad to say, but restarting works. And it makes my life miserable: when something doesn't work, I won't know if it's because I made a mistake or because of some inexplicable quirk of Node/Angular/Visual Code which will only let it work if I restart Visual Code or the server. That's not how professionals work! :-(

Comment: Restart VS Code did nothing till I tried to close all files and confirm saving the .ts file of the error, then close all terminal windows and execute "ng serve" again

Comment: Happened to me with stackblitz.com. And I confirm that reloading the project works

Comment: I fixed it by saving my file. #sad

Comment: I had this issue and I did not need to restart the editor (Intellij). I just needed to stop and start 'ng serve' from the terminal.

Comment: Angular 7 + VSCode here. Experienced it and restarting worked. Kinda annoying lol

Comment: Tried restarting both server and editor, Didn't help. So tried renaming classes and files, eventually it worked.Strange but true.

Comment: Chek if all the files as saved by "Save all" and the run "ng serve" or "ng serve --open"

Answer (score 53):

I got the same error in the same tutorial because I had forgot the **export** keyword for the interface.

Answer (score 48):

The error is because you have not saved the files after creating them.

Try saving all the file by clicking "Save All" on the Editor.

You can see the number of files which are not saved by looking below the "File" menu shown using blue color.

Comment: This was the issue for me. something about the VS Code UI makes it really easy to forget to save

Answer (score 44):

probably you forgot to add "Export" in the class definition.

```
export class Hero {
     id: number;
     name: string;
   }
```

Also, try with

```
export {Hero}
```

at the bottom of your hero.ts class,  and finally, check capital letter file name and class name.

Comment: I did not forget to export. I thought that I maybe had a typo so I copied and pasted your code. This fixed the problem. But then I reverted to my previous code and it worked as well. Something is wrong.

Comment: is this way better than creating a normal `const`?

Answer (score 16):

Restarting my `ng serve` process worked for me

Answer (score 7):

For people getting the same error on [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/)

You will find a **Dependency** tab on the left sidebar of the IDE. Just click the refresh button next to it and you will be good to go.

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to export your class or interface as well.

```
export interface Sort {
    value: string;
    viewValue: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is caused by failer of the `ng serve` serve to automatically pick up a newly added file. To fix this, simply restart your server.

Though closing the reopening the text editor or IDE solves this problem, many people do not want to go through all of the stress of reopening the project. To Fix this without closing the text editor...

In terminal where the server is running,

- **Press `ctrl+C` to stop the server then,**
- **Start the server again: `ng serve`**

That should work.

Answer (score 3):

As I experienced whenever I add a new file to my project, I got to stop and restarting the ng server.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial has you putting all components and the interface file in the same directory hence the relative import `'./hero'` if you want to move it elsewhere you need to change this.

**Edit:** The code may still work but the compiler will complain because you are attempting an import from an incorrect location.  I'd simply change the import based on your structure. For example:

```
app/
  component1/
    component1.ts
  compnent2/
    component2.ts
  hero.ts
```

I would simply change the import to `import {Hero} from '../hero'`.

Comment: My code is perfectly working though, whatever I write, `import {Hero} from './';` or `import {Hero} from './hero';`. I wonder what is the best way to store interface files ?

Comment: Sorry @Zyzle, downvoted as I don't think this addresses the issue the OP had

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue.

I restarted my server and it works fine. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue, tried restarting my server, reopening editor but computer restart did the magic.

P.S: I was facing issue on a windows machine and issue occurred when I moved module into a new folder.

Answer (score 1):

**restart ng serve**

I had the same issue. In order to search for the error, I selected the error and accidentally did a CTRL+C (meaning to copy), which terminated ng serve. On restarting ng serve, the error disappeared :). Sometimes typos and fat fingers help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Editor issue. When you create new files that not using Angular CLI, make sure you go to File > Save All (VS Code) to let the Editor aware of your new changes. Then run "ng serve --open" again. It solved mine. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was accusing that the '*service.ts' is not a module.

To solve it I just added the service within providers in the module.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to do "Save All" from the IDE menu. I had missed this and spent way too much time trying to figure out what was going on

Answer (score 1):

Try to put export before your interface:

```
export interface myModel {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue in VSC. Did restarted the editor and started the application again. It worked fine.

Comment: This is not an answer that would give any insight. Even if you think restarting is the answer to this problem you should say why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found that not only did I have to restart Visual Studio Code but the node server process as well before I could get a good compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I wrote **hero** instead of **Hero**

import the following:

```
import { Hero } from '../Hero';
```

Answer (score 0):

My Resolution,

In my case, I have created a model file and kept it blank,

so when I imported it to other model, It gives me error. so write the definition when you create a model typescript file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occurs when the .ts file is not saved. So make sure all files in the project are saved otherwise try to restart the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt, go to the app folder, e.g. `D:\angular-tour-of-heroes\src\app`

Then create a new file using the following command:

```
ng generate class hero
```

This will create a `hero.ts` file. Then you can paste the export code, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should save all the files. For example html, css, component.ts, module, model files. Open each file and press ctrl-S. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had forgotten to save changes to the file 'app/hero.ts', after saving and restarting ng serve the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
import{observable} from 'rxjs/observable';
```

to

```
import{observable} from 'rxjs';
```

make sure you have save .TS file before compiling.

Answer (score 0):

add this before exporting class

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was running `ng build --prod` with a blank `environment.prod.ts` file

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have created my.ts files from the terminal. Automatically the encoding was set to UTF-16. The Angular compiler can not work with UTF-16 files (only tested this on Windows).

After I changed the encoding to UTF-8 everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Save your foo.component.ts file and everything should work fine. Most of the answers here are telling you to close editor. When u close editor , all unsaved changes automatically save and hence it starts working the next time u load your project into editor :-)