# Typescript: *.ts is not a module

Tags: typescript

I've just installed a self-made npm library on my project.

npm is able to generate every artifacts and I've published them. So, now I'm able to use the services I've made: `UsersApi`.

The package structure is:

```
ts
│───configuration.ts
│───index.ts
│───variables.ts
│
└───api
    ───api.ts
    ───UsersApi.ts
```

The content of `index.ts` is:

```
export * from './api/api';
export * from './variables';
export * from './configuration';
```

The content of `api/api.ts` is:

```
export * from './UsersApi';
```

And the content of `api/UserApi.ts` is a regular typescript content:

```
/**
 * Living API
 * desc
 *
 * OpenAPI spec version: 1.0.2
 * 
 *
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program.
 * https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */

import { Inject, Injectable, Optional }                      from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams }                    from '@angular/http';
import { RequestMethod, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Response, ResponseContentType }                     from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }                                        from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

//import * as models                                           from '../model/models';
import { BASE_PATH }                                         from '../variables';
import { Configuration }                                     from '../configuration';

/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable member-ordering */


@Injectable()
export class UsersApi {
    protected basePath = 'http://localhost:8082/commty/cmng';
    public defaultHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
    public configuration: Configuration = new Configuration();

    constructor(protected http: Http, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string, @Optional() configuration: Configuration) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
        if (configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Extends object by coping non-existing properties.
     * @param objA object to be extended
     * @param objB source object
     */
    private extendObj<T1,T2>(objA: T1, objB: T2) {
        for(let key in objB){
            if(objB.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                (objA as any)[key] = (objB as any)[key];
            }
        }
        return <T1&T2>objA;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     * 
     * @param user username
     * @param passwd passwd
     */
    public create(user: string, passwd: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<{}> {
        return this.createWithHttpInfo(user, passwd, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * User exists
     * 
     * @param user username
     */
    public exists(user: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.existsWithHttpInfo(user, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            });
    }


    /**
     * Add user
     * 
     * @param user username
     * @param passwd passwd
     */
    public createWithHttpInfo(user: string, passwd: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<Response> {
        const path = this.basePath + `/users`;

        let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845
        // verify required parameter 'user' is not null or undefined
        if (user === null || user === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter user was null or undefined when calling create.');
        }
        // verify required parameter 'passwd' is not null or undefined
        if (passwd === null || passwd === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter passwd was null or undefined when calling create.');
        }


        // to determine the Content-Type header
        let consumes: string[] = [
        ];

        // to determine the Accept header
        let produces: string[] = [
            'application/json'
        ];





        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Put,
            headers: headers,
            search: queryParameters
        });

        // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037
        if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
            requestOptions = this.extendObj(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
        }

        return this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
    }

    /**
     * User exists
     * 
     * @param user username
     */
    public existsWithHttpInfo(user: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<Response> {
        const path = this.basePath + `/users`;

        let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845
        // verify required parameter 'user' is not null or undefined
        if (user === null || user === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter user was null or undefined when calling exists.');
        }


        // to determine the Content-Type header
        let consumes: string[] = [
        ];

        // to determine the Accept header
        let produces: string[] = [
            'application/json'
        ];





        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            headers: headers,
            search: queryParameters
        });

        // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037
        if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
            requestOptions = this.extendObj(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
        }

        return this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
    }

}
```

I'm getting the next message:

```
file: 'file:///d%3A/projects/living/user-platform/project/node_modules/cest/ts/api/api.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'File 'd:/projects/living/user-platform/project/node_modules/cest/ts/api/UsersApi.ts' is not a module.'
at: '1,15'
source: 'ts'
```

This is the `tsconfig`'s content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": "./ts",
        "outDir": "js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "js"
    ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you should specify default export: "export default class UsersApi {" or specify module type in tsconfig file.

Comment: What does `default` stand for? Previously, I've never set it up and it work before. Is it possible?

Comment: Each module can optionally export a default export. Default exports are marked with the keyword default; and there can only be one default export per module. Yes it's optional. And this shouldn't affect module rerefencing.

Comment: Have you specified module type in tsconfig file for "UsersApi.ts"?

Comment: I've just edited the post including `tsconfig` content. I've just realized `js` *outDir* folder is not generated...

Comment: Your tsconfig looks ok for me.

Comment: It's really unbelievable. I have absolutly no idea what's hapenning. I'm getting two messages: `Module "/cest/ts/index" has no exported member 'UsersApi'` and `UsersApi.ts is not a module`. Isn't there any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding may solve the problem.

```
npm run build
```

I was getting the same error with an Angular project and i found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629517/file-app-hero-ts-is-not-a-module-error-in-the-console-where-to-store-interfac). I hope it helps for people who will come later :)

```
^C
ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. Because I have two files of the same module, one is an empty file `UsersApi.ts` and one is `UsersApi.tsx`.

just delete the empty one