# "mock-heroes.ts' is not a module" error from official Angular doc

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to follow the official Angular doc:

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

but can't proceed due to this error:

Failed to compile.

```
C:/Users/username/Desktop/my-app/src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts (3,24): 
File 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/my-app/src/app/mock-heroes.ts' is not a module.
```

My code is exactly the same as in the tutorial, this is really frustrating conming from the official doc and makes me not even want to learn angular :( Anyone have any idea how to get past it?

**mock-heroes.ts:**

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

**hero.ts:**

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**heroes.components.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

    heroes = HEROES;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

**heroes.component.html:**

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You said your file is `heroe.ts` yet you are `import { Hero } from '../hero';` - is that a typo in your filename or just in your question?

Comment: @JamieBarker good catch, no that was just a typo in the question. I will edit it.

Comment: Also you can download the project at the [bottom of that page you linked](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#final-code-review). It can be a good idea to download it or look at the Plunkr and compare what you have to what they have to see what the problem is (assuming theirs works correctly)

Comment: This is opinion-based, as I noted in a quora answer, the Angular team has taken on too much work and hasn't updated the documentation very well. I had the same problems when trying to follow their tutorial so I gave up and just followed other books and the API documentation.

Comment: @RudolfOlah I followed it myself very recently, didn't have any problems IIRC.

Comment: @TK123 [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629517/file-app-hero-ts-is-not-a-module-error-in-the-console-where-to-store-interfac) might help.

Comment: @Jamie Barker I downloaded the files and they work, still not sure what the issue on my version was.

Comment: @JamieBarker which version/month did you try it?

Comment: @RudolfOlah It would have been roughly the middle of October 2017, and whichever was the most recent version at that point.

Answer (score 5):

I assume the OP has solved his issue but for anyone who ever comes across this issue, here we go.

I had the same exact issue just like yours. I checked through answers which stated to [restart the editor or restart the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629517/file-app-hero-ts-is-not-a-module-error-in-the-console-where-to-store-interfac) .i.e. `ng serve`. Both did not work for me.

I am relatively new to VS code (btw this is the IDE I am using) and also to angular2, hence [this](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial (Tutorial: Tour of Heroes).

The issue was that I had created mock-heroes.ts, populated it with the source code but did not save the contents due to a windows crash. VS code must have a cached version which retained the unsaved source. When I opened the IDE once more the file was intact but had not realized there was a blue dot on the files icon. Upon hovering over, it showed "1 unsaved file". Thus the issue that `mock-heroes.ts` is not a module, the file exists and I can import it, but it contains no saved code so it's not a module, yet.

CTRL + S ... sorted. `ng server` and it runs like a charm.

Moments after the biggest face palm in history I am writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @JamieBarker said, the said erro happens when you add a new class outside from your editor or keep running your angular cli `ng serve`.

Actually your editor or 'ng serve' is not able to find the newly created files.

I got the same error while using `ng serve --open`. I stopped it and used `ng serve` and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, But problem resolves when you save **mock-heroes.ts** and **heroes.components.ts**. if problem doesn't solve then stop **ng serve** and restart it again.