# TypeScript file "is not a module"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a really basic Typescript file being imported into a Register.tsx file. I keep getting the following error when building with npm.

> test.ts' is not a module

test.ts

```
export class Tester {
    test(): string {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Register.tsx

```
import { Tester } from "./../test"
```

I've read several different solutions but I can't see anything I'm doing wrong or different. Am I missing something glaringly obvious? I'm new to Typescript / npm / Webpack.

Comment: I changed the file to a .tsx extension and it compiles now. I'm not happy with this temporary solution though.

Comment: You might try some of the answers of this question: [File 'app/hero.ts' is not a module error in the console, where to store interfaces files in directory structure with angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34629517)

Answer (score 4):

Does test.ts export anything else or access the `module` object? My experience is that TypeScript throws the 'not a module' warning whenever if it sees the NodeJS `module` object, which NodeJS uses for exports instead of the TS `export` notation.

My team has an environment in which we include plain JavaScript files into certain TypeScript projects, and we get the same 'not a module' warning whenever importing anything with lines like:
`module.exports = X` or `module.exports.thing = X`
(which happens to be all of the plain-Javascript files.)

Comment: It doesn't. The file exists entirely of what was posted above. I tried to make it as bare bones as possible to fix the compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

When this happened to me, restarting my yarn dev did solved the issue. It seems tsc is not restarted completely when watch reload, and that it does not discover new files properly...